# Sample Factory Pattern Output not displaying

Tags: design-patterns, c++14, factory-pattern

I'm trying to implement the GoF Factory Pattern, but for some reason I am not getting the output.

PS. All the files below have been compiled with -std=gnu++14 parameter.

Below is a `shape.h` header file where I have defined an (abstract) class `Shape`

```
class Shape
{
    public:
        virtual void draw() {}
};
```

Now I have another header file `shapes.h` where I have written three concrete classes that extend the `Shape` class. I have also overridden the `draw()` inside each of these classes.

```
#include "shape.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class Circle : public Shape
{
    public:
        void draw()
        {
            cout << "Inside Circle::draw()\n";
        }
};

class Square : public Shape
{
    public:
        void draw()
        {
            cout << "Inside Square::draw()\n";
        }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
    public:
        void draw()
        {
            cout << "Inside Rectangle::draw()\n";
        }
};
```

Now I have a `Shapefactory` class, defined in `shapefactory.h` that will give me a `Shape` depending upon the parameter passed in the function:

```
#include "shapes.h"
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using std::string;

class Shapefactory
{
    private:
        bool iequals(const string& a, const string& b)
        {
            return std::equal
                (a.begin(), a.end(),
                b.begin(), b.end(),
                [](char a, char b) {
                    return tolower(a) == tolower(b);
                }
            );
        }
    public:
        Shape get_shape(string shape)
        {
            if (iequals(shape , "CIRCLE"))
                return Circle();
            else if (iequals(shape , "SQUARE"))
                return Square();
            else if (iequals(shape , "RECTANGLE"))
                return Rectangle();
            else
                return Circle();
        }
};
```

Finally here is the our driver program:

```
#include "shapefactory.h"

int main()
{
    Shapefactory shapeFactory;
    Shape shape1 = shapeFactory.get_shape("CIRCLE");
    shape1.draw();

    Shape shape2 = shapeFactory.get_shape("RECTANGLE");
    shape2.draw();

    Shape shape3 = shapeFactory.get_shape("SQUARE");
    shape3.draw();

    return 0;
}
```

None of the shape's `draw()` gives an output. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing return type of get_shape() to Shape*

```
Shape* get_shape(string shape)
    {
        if (iequals(shape , "CIRCLE"))
            return new Circle();
        else if (iequals(shape , "SQUARE"))
            return new Square();
        else if (iequals(shape , "RECTANGLE"))
            return new Rectangle();
        else
            return NULL;
    }
```

Similarly, I also had to modify the Driver

```
int main()
{
    Shapefactory shapeFactory;
    Shape *shape1 = shapeFactory.get_shape("CIRCLE");
    (*shape1).draw();

    Shape *shape2 = shapeFactory.get_shape("RECTANGLE");
    (*shape2).draw();

    Shape *shape3 = shapeFactory.get_shape("SQUARE");
    (*shape3).draw();

    return 0;
}
```